# My average result is adding 1 to the correct answer

Tags: c#, arrays, average

I have absolutely no coding experience, but i'm trying to help a student with a program which is meant to display an average of numbers which have been placed in an array by the user.

It's giving us the *correct average result*, but *adding 1* to it. i can't really understand what's happening in his code, but i have a feeling it is at the end of this line:

```
 for (intLoopCount = 0; intLoopCount < intRecordCount; intLoopCount++)
```

any help would be very much appreciated as i'm out of my depth.

full section of code:

```
private static double AverageReading()
{
        double dblAverage;
        double dblTotal = intRecordCount;

        if (intRecordCount == 0) //no books chosen
        {
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
                int intLoopCount = 0;


                for (intLoopCount = 0; intLoopCount < intRecordCount; intLoopCount++)
                {
                        dblTotal = dblTotal + intLoanNumber[intLoopCount];
                }

                dblAverage = dblTotal / intRecordCount; 

                return dblAverage;
         }
}
```

Comment: `double dblTotal = 0;` not `double dblTotal = intRecordCount;`

Comment: `double dblTotal = intRecordCount;` looks very odd - why are you starting with this number? According to your description you want the average of the numbers in an array, why are you adding the number of elements to that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not the place to let others debug your code. Start by reading the [tour] and [ask], and [edit] your question to show some example input, expected output and actual output, and show that you have used the debugger to inspect your variables at every step of the program. The line you suspect does nothing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather use *Linq* in the context (if we have `Any` items return `Average` of them, otherwise `0`):

```
  private static double AverageReading() => intLoanNumber.Any()
    ? intLoanNumber.Average()
    : 0.0;
```

If you prefer *loop* implementation:

```
 private static double AverageReading() {
   if (intRecordCount == 0) 
     return 0.0;

   double dblTotal = 0.0; // <- 0.0, not intRecordCount

   // probably, condition should be "i < intLoanNumber.Length" not "i < intRecordCount"
   for (int i = 0; i < intRecordCount; ++i)
     dblTotal += intLoanNumber[i];

   // probably, "dblTotal / intLoanNumber.Length" instead of "dblTotal / intRecordCount"
   return dblTotal / intRecordCount;   
 }
```